# TreeListView from database on two rows for FAQ user solution

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, treeview

How can I crate a TreeView of two colums from a table?

The solution I'm creating is a FAQ for users on an ordering site. I have two rows, one consisting of the questions and the other is consisting of the answers.

[My Faq table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jId5R.png)

[This is what I have and I only want the questions to be shown before click to show the answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjj6j.png)

[This is what I want and trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk3wZ.png)

```
        function ShowAllFaqs(faqs) {
        var strResult = "<table class='table table-boarded'>";
        $.each(faqs, function (i, p) {
            strResult += "<tr><th>" + p.Question+ "</th></tr>";
            strResult += "<td>" + p.Answer+ "</td>";
        strResult += "</table>";
        $("#faqs").html(strResult);
    }
```

This is my script and it displays in a div.

Is there any other more efficient/easier way to do this?

I'm trying with TreeView but can't figure it out..